# How MAVEN load "same" dependencies JAR file?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies

I have following lines in a Maven POM file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

On MAVEN repository, on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa/4.2.1
it is indicated that `querydsl-api` depends of `slf4j-api` version `1.6.1`.

When MAVEN build the application, which version of `slf4j-api` is used ?

When Java application is loaded, which version of `slf4j-api` is used ?

What happens if `slf4j-api` is defined before `querydsl-jpa` ?

What happens if `slf4j-api` version used in `querydsl-jpa` is lower than version defined in application POM file ?

Comment: Short answer: Try it

Comment: You can use "maven dependency hell" as the starting point in your Googling.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about *Maven dependency mediation*.

Maven builds a tree from your dependencies and consolidates this tree into a list. In this list, each dependency may appear only once. So if there are several different versions in your tree, Maven needs to choose one.

Maven has a "nearest dependency" standard rule that roughly states: The direct dependencies count more than first level transitive dependencies which count more than second level transitive dependencies and so on.

It is not possible to define a different rule, but you can specify a version in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your pom. This version overwrites all transitively defined versions.

The hardest part is to figure out which version may be "right", i.e. compatible with all use cases. There is not automatic way to do that.